# Play Framework will not recognize Java Options (JVM args) passed in Build.scala

Tags: sbt, playframework-2.2

All,

I'm trying to get Play Framework to recognize JVM arguments in all modes (test, run start) by setting them in Build.scala.

Unfortunately, Play ignores everything I've thrown at it.

I've set Keys.javaOptions and Keys.fork, but it SBT flat out ignores the fork command. I also tried going at this by replacing Build.scala with build.sbt, but that doesn't seem to work either.

I realize you can set JAVA_OPTS or PLAY_OPTS in your environment, but this is really lousy way of doing things. One should be able to configure this at the application level and play should be smart enough to either spawn a new process or re-launch itself with the appropriate configuration.

Anyone able to get this to work? If so, can you provide a complete, working solution?

Answer (score 4):

The Play Framework SBT keys override javaOptions you pass, and therefore it will not work.
The way to do it ,according to the documentation, is to pass those arguments at the start command.

The syntax changes a bit from version to version, but at [2.2.x](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ProductionConfiguration) it is:

`$ /path/to/bin/<project-name> -J-Xms128M -J-Xmx512m -J-server`

Comment: Yeah, but it still seems like a slightly kludgey way to do it. From a config management perspective, it'd be ideal if we didn't have to use command line arguments or environment variables.

Hopefully this will be addressed in a future version of Play.

Comment: What I did in the project I'm currently working on, is write a small shell script that sets JAVA_OPTS for that session, and then runs Play. This pretty much solves the problem, as you can keep the configuration in a file, and still not set it as an environment variable.

Comment: Yeah, that's another option.

I found what looks like a bug in the latest version of play though. I had to set java_opts (lower case) for it to recognize the params. Uppercase was ignored.